# Decompress PDF FlateDecode Filter Annotations with PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, filter, zlib, pypdf

I am trying the following code to extract the destination or uri of hyperlinks in PDF file via PyPDF2, but I encountered some encoded destinations. I tried to decompress them by `filter.decodeStreamData()`; however, my result is still unreadable :(

I am not able to solve the problem, please help.

```
import PyPDF2
import zlib
from PyPDF2 import filters

PDFFile = open()

PDF = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(PDFFile)
pages = PDF.getNumPages()
annotatn = '/Annots'
hyperlink = '/A'

ob = {'/URI', '/D'}


for page in range(pages):
    print("Current Page: {}".format(page+1))
    pageSliced = PDF.getPage(page)
    pageObject = pageSliced.getObject()

    if annotatn in pageObject.keys():
        i = 0
        for annot in pageObject[annotatn]:
            i = i + 1
            print("Link {}".format(i))
            ann = annot.getObject()
            if '/Dest' in ann.keys():
                dest = ann['/Dest'][0].getObject()
                data = dest['/Contents'].getObject()
                s = data._data
                contnt = filters.decodeStreamData(data)

            if hyperlink in ann.keys():
                links = ann[hyperlink]
                for link in links:
                    if link in ob:
                        print(ann[hyperlink][link])
```

Comment: Which version of PyPDF2 were you using? What was the error you were seing? What was the expected result? Can you share such a PDF? Do you have this issue only with that PDF or with all PDF documents?